# Using `capitalize` or `capitalize!`

Tags: ruby, capitalize

Codecademy wants me to write code as follows to capitalize the first letter for what I input:

```
print "What's your first name?"
firstname = gets.chomp
firstname2 = firstname.capitalize
firstname.capitalize!
puts "Your first name is #{first_name}!"
```

However, I wrote it as:

```
print "What's your first name?"
firstname = gets.chomp.capitalize
puts "Your first name is #{firstname}!"
```

They both produce the same results, yet my way seems a lot easier and to the point. I was wondering if these two codes while producing the same result are actually any different. Is there a specific reason to go through the extra steps and repetition using `firstname.capitalize!` as opposed to just adding `capitalize` on to `gets`?

Comment: [There is more than one way to do it](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ThereIsMoreThanOneWayToDoIt) :-)

Main thing to note is the difference between `capitalize` and `capitalize!`

Comment: The first code is not using `firstname2` anywhere. It does not make sense.

Comment: @sawa I'm just going by the lesson.  Pretty new to all of this.  It says it is assigning the results to `firstname2`.

Comment: Yes, it does assign. And it does not make sense to do so unless it is followed by some more code.

Answer (score 4):

`capitalize` returns a new string with the first letter capitalized

`capitalize!` modifies or mutates the original string

```
2.1.1 :001 > string = 'hello'
 => "hello"
2.1.1 :002 > string.capitalize
 => "Hello"
2.1.1 :003 > string
 => "hello"
2.1.1 :004 > string.capitalize!
 => "Hello"
2.1.1 :005 > string
 => "Hello"
```

In general, mutating objects is not *considered* a good practice as it could lead to unexpected results.

Consider the following scenario:

```
def i_will_capitalize(string)
  string.capitalize!
  puts string
end

def i_expect_the_original_string(string)
  puts string
end

string = 'hello'

i_will_capitalize(string) # Returns 'Hello'
i_expect_the_original_string(string) # Returns 'Hello' as well!
```

Comment: Perfect thanks.  So is the way I wrote it `gets.chomp.capitalize` good practice for that situation?

Comment: Yes. Also note that *usually* any Ruby method that ends with a bang(`!`) modifies the receiver/original object

Comment: "mutating objects is not considered a good practice" is perhaps a little strong. For example, `Hash#merge!` (a.k.a. `update`) is extremely useful in building hashes.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I prefixed it with "In general". Of course mutation can lead to better performance and there are cases where it is fine to mutate e.g. .each_with_object({}) { |x, hash| hash.merge!(hello: x). But still it depends what you are mutating. Also, I think it's good for new developers to understand what ! methods actually do and their side effects hence my example

Answer (score 3):

`capitalize!` modifies the receiver string whereas `capitalize` creates a new string. In cases where you are not using the receiver string somewhere else in the original form, it is more efficient to use the former; it saves memory. In a short script like this, it will not make much difference, but in larger programs that do bunches of huge string operations, it makes a huge difference. If my memory is correct, I read something written by a SASS developer that just by replacing the `gsub`s they had in an earlier version of code by `gsub!`, they gained great performance improvement.

On the other hand, if there is a possibility that you want to use the string in the form before capitalization, then you should go with your way.